# MySQL Leading 0's Date Formating

Tags: mysql, string, date, formatting

I currently have the following select statement:

```
SELECT CONCAT(TRUNCATE(HOUR("215:00:36")/24,0),":",HOUR("215:00:36")%24,":",MINUTE("215:00:36")) AS case_aging
```

This will convert h:m:s to d:h:m. This works fine but the output is

8:23:0

I want the output to be 08:23:00 without having to hardcode 0's. I know I should be using date_format to accomplish this but I get NULL when i try to do so, probably because of the way this is formated as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a [LPAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) to your select. Like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LPAD(TRUNCATE(HOUR("215:00:36")/24,0),2,'0'),":",LPAD(HOUR("215:00:36")%24,2,'0'),":",LPAD(MINUTE("215:00:36"),2,'0') ) AS case_aging
```

Comment: Error Code: 1582
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'LPAD'

Comment: @Zeusftw Answer revised. Try it again.

Comment: ripped it brah fuark